# Search cell contains text and replace with letter in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need a Excel macro that would replace cell with a represented letter.  For example, in the cell originally I have the following text: 9x10 Deck, 3x6 Beam and 12" Pole and I need to remove it and replace cells with "D" (for 9x10 Deck), "B" (for 3x6 Beam) and "P" (for 12" Pole).

I only had able to ran one parameter at a time, below is the code, it does the work but don't seems doing it right.

I would like to run macro to search cells that contain "Beam", "Pole", "Deck" and replaced the cell with corresponding letters, such as "B", "P".

```
Sub CleanUp()
Dim r As Range
Dim s As String, v As String
s = "D"
For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    v = r.Text
    If InStr(1, v, s) > 0 Then
        r.Value = s
    End If
Next r 
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please add some code what you have started with & where you have stuck.

Comment: not much clear... what if they contain all three? share what you've tried so far!

Answer (score 0):

```
A           B   C   D   E   F 
9x10 Deck       D           D
3x6 Beam            B       B
12" Pole                P   P
2x4 strut
```

since nether find or search can handle multiple functions (always returns #value if not present)  I would make 4 columns and concatenate them together.

the formula would be like this for each letter:

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND("D",A1),"D",""),"")
```

then this to sum it up:

```
=CONCATENATE(C1,D1,E1)
```